# Unable to setup Webpack Boilerplate using node

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to setup a project boilerplate using node webpack. I have written all the code that requires to set it up but unfortunately, I am getting an error "unable to load ./path/webpack.config.development.js' config" from Webpack CLI.

#Package.json code is

```
{
  "name": "floema",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config-build.js",
    "development": "webpack serve --progress --config webpack.config.development.js",
    "start": "npm run development"
  },
  "author": "Sanwal Manzoor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "webpack": "^5.64.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

#Webpack.config.build.js code is:

```
const path =require('path')

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const config = require('./webpack.config.js')

module.exports = merge(config, {
  mode: 'production',

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ]
})
```

#Webpack.config.development.js code is

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const path = require('path')

const config = require('./webpack.config.js')

module.exports = merge(config, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  }
})
```

#Webpack.config.js code is

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')


const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

const IS_DEVELOPMENT = process.evn.NODE_ENV === 'dev'

const dirApp = path.join(__dirname, 'app')
const dirAssets = path.join(__dirname, 'assets')
const dirStyles = path.join(__dirname, 'styles')

console.log(dirApp, dirAssets, dirStyles)
```

The Error I am getting is

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'E:\N_Projects\FLOEMA\webpack.config.development.js' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'NODE_ENV')
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\N_Projects\FLOEMA\webpack.config.js:8:36)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\N_Projects\FLOEMA\webpack.config.development.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
```

Comment: `process.env` not 'evn'

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This issue was resolved by downgrading to some early versions of webpack packages.

The solution was to use:

npm install --save-dev webpack@5.33.2 webpack-cli@4.9.0 webpack-dev-server@3.11.2 webpack-merge@5.7.3

I think the main issue was caused by a newer version of webpack-cli